# Help getting the following create table function to work with mysql and C#

Tags: c#, mysql, create-table

```
string createTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + m_strDatabase + "_TimeLogs (logName VARCHAR(16), logTime INTEGER, logCountry TEXT, UNIQUE(logName)) TYPE=MyISAM;";
```

When this runs, no table is created.
No errors either.

Im using an ODBC connector.

the variable passes in the db name, so that the table created would be   users_TimeLogs if the database was called users for example.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Where's the rest of the code that actually executes this string?

Comment: I didn't include it because I know that bit works, i've used it before..  Its the first time i've tried to create a table though.  I'm using the OdbcCommand, and then OdbcCom.ExecuteNonQuery().

Comment: Creating table and inserting records are different things.
Do you have enough rights to create table?

Comment: yeah I do, it executes perfectly through phpMyAdmin.. Just not when running in the C# code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd forgotten that way way above in my code I had a constraint to only run if a list.count > 0, and since I'm only testing at this stage the list was empty..

Comment: "I didn't include [the rest of the code] because I know that bit works"... :D